# how to load specific files/urls based on a database query

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to alter a piece of code that will allow me to position an image left, right or centred.
I have been able to create radio buttons that populate a table on the database but now I want to pull that information out and create an IF statement that will then open a specified page depending on the result.

For example, If I choose the 'right' radio button, this will then populate the database with the id and the 'right' value. I then want to pull the value from the database so if the value is 'right' the newsitem2.php page will load.

This is the code I have in order to do this:

```
if ("" . $tnrow['newsimage'] . "" == "none") { 

}else {  

$radio="SELECT imageposition FROM newsimage";  

if ("$radio" == Centre) {

<p class='newsmore'> <a href='newsitem3.php?i=" . $tnrow['niid'] . "'>Read More</a></p>  

}  

if ("$radio" == Right) {

<p class='newsmore'> <a href='newsitem2.php?i=" . $tnrow['niid'] . "'>Read More</a></p>  

}  

if ("$radio" == Left) {

<p class='newsmore'> <a href='newsitem.php?i=" . $tnrow['niid'] . "'>Read More</a></p>  

}
```

However, it is not loading each page it just loads the 'newsitem' page with the image on the left. is there any reason for this?

Comment: Start with a search for a PHP MySQL tutorial. This is not a code writing service, its a why does this code not work service. So you have to write some and then ask why its not working. PS Dont use the mysql_* function they will soon be removed!

Comment: I have edited the question so you can now see that I was asking for help on the code shown above. I wasn't asking for anyone to write the code for me. @RiggsFolly

Answer (score 0):

You don't make any call to your database, so `$radio` is just a String when you use it for now (representing the query) ; you have to send this query to your database (using for example a wrapper like PDO), and then get the result back.

Another thing, are `Right`, `Left`, ... constants or enum values ? 'Cause if they're not, you also have to put them into quotes, in order to be interpreted as String

There are a lot of weird instructions in your code, you should probably get more informations on PHP, 'cause you doesn't really seem to understand the concepts for now. Get a good tutorial/book, and you'll see that what you want to do is pretty easy when you got the ideas behind. ;)

Comment: I do call to the database but I haven't shown the whole code, just the bit I'm struggling with. Could you recommend a good online tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

Your `IF's` are all wrong. I assume the value of $radio is a string?

```
if ("$radio" == Centre) {
```

Should be

```
if ($radio == 'Centre') {
```

And so on for all the others